# "getOutputStream()" has already been called for this response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat8

i'm working on a project with Spring, i have this problem, i google the error message and i did find a solutions even all SO posts about this same problem

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: "getOutputStream()" has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:578)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:109)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:115)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:175)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Pages.generate_jsp._jspService(generate_jsp.java:209)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

***this is my controller :***

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/GenerateM")
    public String genererGet(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
   // Some code ...

        OutputStream out;
        try {
            response.setContentType("rtf");
            String filename = name + ".out.rtf";
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = " + filename);
            out = response.getOutputStream();
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(rtf.getRtfOutput()));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int length;
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException a) {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "generate";
    }
```

i saw many SO posts like : [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776142/getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065561/java-lang-illegalstateexception-getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-t) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909657/java-lang-illegalstateexception-getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-t) but no solution for me

**can some one help ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You start by writing a response by yourself, and then return the name of the view, and thus telling Spring that it should generate an HTML page using the `generate.jsp`.

Make your method return `void` instead of a String. An HTTP response can have only one body: either it's a file attachment, or an HTML page, but not both.

Comment: now it gives me an `org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` error message like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303241/java-io-ioexception-an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-you)

Comment: Don't close the response OutputStream. That's the container's job.

Answer (score 0):

@JB Nizet Thank's for help. In my case, I retured `ModelAndView` ojbect when download failing to forward error page:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/downloadfile.action" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView downloadFile(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Model model)
{
  catch (Excetion e) {
    return errorPage
  }   
}
```

I change that to return `null`